# How can I fix the error 0xc000007b in DirectX9 SDK

Tags: directx-9

Already reinstalled the Windows.
Tried reinstalling everything possible, .NET framework, DirectX, Visual essential but nothing.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  Where exactly are you getting this error from? (API call, program, debugger?)  Are you trying to install the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) or something even older?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for all the essential for file that is required for direct x9 and try again.. sometimes some files are missed and that causes the trouble...